# C++ - Diamond-Square algorithm output is random and noisy

Tags: c++, algorithm, terrain, procedural-generation, heightmap

I have implemented a rough interpretation of the *Diamond-Square algorithm* in C++ to create some semi-realistic fractal terrain, but the output just seems like a random y value at each point rather than smooth rocky shapes. I have altered parameters but feel like an outside look at the code might help me understand the issue. Here are examples of the output:

I got this:

[image: Example]

And should look like this:

[image: What it *should* look like (this is loaded from a file)]

The code:

```
//Diamond-square algorithm
HeightMap::HeightMap(float maxY) {
//type = GL_POINTS; 
//type = GL_LINES;
numVertices = RAW_WIDTH*RAW_HEIGHT; //256^2 squares => 257^2 vertices
numIndices = (RAW_WIDTH - 1)*(RAW_HEIGHT - 1) * 6; //each square is 2 triangles (6 indices)
vertices = new Vector3[numVertices];
textureCoords = new Vector2[numVertices];
indices = new GLuint[numIndices];
colours = new Vector4[numVertices];

int cornerA, cornerB, cornerC, cornerD; //Identify corners
cornerA = 0;
cornerB = RAW_WIDTH - 1;
cornerC = RAW_WIDTH*RAW_HEIGHT - RAW_WIDTH;
cornerD = RAW_WIDTH*RAW_HEIGHT - 1;

//Create vertices
for (int x = 0; x < RAW_WIDTH; ++x) {
    for (int z = 0; z < RAW_HEIGHT; ++z) {
        int offset = (x * RAW_WIDTH) + z;
        float y = 0; //Start with vertices set flat
        if (offset == cornerA ||
            offset == cornerB ||
            offset == cornerC ||
            offset == cornerD) {
            vertices[offset] = Vector3(x * HEIGHTMAP_X, maxY/2, z * HEIGHTMAP_Z); //Initialise corners to mid height
            std::cout << "Corners: " << offset << std::endl;
        }

        if (vertices[offset] == Vector3(0, 0, 0)) {
            vertices[offset] = Vector3(x * HEIGHTMAP_X, y * HEIGHTMAP_Y, z * HEIGHTMAP_Z);
        }
        //  textureCoords[offset] = Vector2(x * HEIGHTMAP_TEX_X, z * HEIGHTMAP_TEX_Z);
    }
}

Vector3 tl, tr, bl, br;
tl = vertices[cornerA];
tr = vertices[cornerB];
bl = vertices[cornerC];
br = vertices[cornerD];

float roughness = 1.0f;

Square square = Square(tl, tr, bl, br);
diamondSquare(vertices, numVertices, square, roughness);

//Colour
for (int x = 0; x < RAW_WIDTH; ++x) {
    for (int z = 0; z < RAW_HEIGHT; ++z) {
        int offset = (x*RAW_WIDTH) + z;
        float shade;
        if (vertices[offset].y > 0) {
            shade = 1 - 1.0f / (vertices[offset].y / maxY * 2);
        }
        else {
            shade = 0.1f;
        }
        colours[offset] = Vector4(shade, shade, shade, 1.0f);
        //Colour any vertex that hasn't been passed over red
        if (vertices[offset].y == maxY / 2 + 100) {
            colours[offset] = Vector4(1, 0, 0, 1);
        }
    }
}

//Create indices
numIndices = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < RAW_WIDTH - 1; ++x) {
    for (int z = 0; z < RAW_HEIGHT - 1; ++z) {
        int a = (x*(RAW_WIDTH)) + z;
        int b = ((x + 1)*(RAW_WIDTH)) + z;
        int c = ((x + 1)*(RAW_WIDTH)) + (z + 1);
        int d = (x*(RAW_WIDTH)) + (z + 1);

        indices[numIndices++] = c;
        indices[numIndices++] = b;
        indices[numIndices++] = a;
        indices[numIndices++] = a;
        indices[numIndices++] = d;
        indices[numIndices++] = c;

    }
}
BufferData();
```

}

```
void HeightMap::squareStep(Vector3 vertices[], int len, Vector3 tl, Vector3 tr, Vector3 bl, Vector3 br, float mid, float roughness) {
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    Vector3 top = (tl + tr) / 2;
    Vector3 bot = (bl + br) / 2;
    Vector3 left = (tl + bl) / 2;
    Vector3 right = (tr + br) / 2;
    top.y = 0;
    bot.y = 0;
    left.y = 0;
    right.y = 0;
    if (vertices[i] == top ||
        vertices[i] == bot ||
        vertices[i] == left ||
        vertices[i] == right) {
        float y = rand() % (int)(mid/5);
        y *= roughness;
        vertices[i] = Vector3(vertices[i].x, mid + y, vertices[i].z); //Set Diamond centre points to mid height + rand
        std::cout << "Square: " << vertices[i];
    }
}
```

}

```
float HeightMap::diamondStep(Vector3 vertices[], int len, Vector3 tl, Vector3 tr, Vector3 bl, Vector3 br, float roughness) {
float avg;
float y;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        Vector3 corners = (tl + tr + bl + br) / 4;
        avg = corners.y;
        y = rand() % (int)(avg/5);
        y *= roughness;
        corners.y = 0;
        if (vertices[i] == corners) {
            vertices[i] = Vector3(vertices[i].x, avg + y, vertices[i].z);         //Set Square centre point to avg height of corners + rand
            std::cout << "Diamond: " << vertices[i];
        }
    }
return avg + y;
```

}

```
void HeightMap::diamondSquare(Vector3 vertices[], int numVertices, Square s, float roughness) {
Vector3 tl = s.tl;
Vector3 tr = s.tr;
Vector3 bl = s.bl;
Vector3 br = s.br;
float mid = diamondStep(vertices, numVertices, tl, tr, bl, br, roughness);
squareStep(vertices, numVertices, tl, tr, bl, br, mid, roughness);
roughness *= 0.75f;
if (s.width > 2 * HEIGHTMAP_X) {
    std::vector<Square> squares = s.split();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        diamondSquare(vertices, numVertices, squares[i], roughness);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what do you mean with "rough interpretation"? Maybe your Example is a rough interpretation of What it should look like.

Comment: Too lazy to go through your code so just hints: 1. recursion is really tricky on this due to overlaps and edge crossing irregularities simpler/faster/better is to use iteration instead see my [Iterative Diamond&Square in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36258843/2521214) 2. looks like you are not adjusting randomness (the magnitude should lovering with recursion layer) or not using average position as base (midpoint displacement) but that is just visual impression you need to check it (could be also wrong recursion). Also look at [island generator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36647622/2521214)

Answer (score 0):

Your midpoint calculations look wrong. The algorithm should sets the midpoint of that square or diamond to be the average of the four corner points plus a random value. But in your code I see this:

`y = rand() % (int)(avg/5);`

This basically says, set y to a random number between zero & one fifth of the average of the corners. Instead I would expect to see something like this:

```
// get a random float in the range 0 to 1
float r = (float)(rand()) / (float)(RAND_MAX);
// scale r to be in the range -magnitude to magnitude
r = (r * 2 * magnitude) - magnitude;
// add the scaled random value to the average of the corners
y = avg + r;
```

Note: it's possible that this approach will give you y values less than zero. If that's a problem, normalize the data by finding the lowest value & subtracting that amount from each y.