# Python 3.4.3 Diamond-Square Algorithm is producing odd results

Tags: python, algorithm

I am currently stumped by an artefact in my code. It appears to produce very sharp points in a grid pattern that have a noticeable difference in value to their neighbours.

I am following the blog post at http://www.bluh.org/code-the-diamond-square-algorithm/ and converting from whichever language they are using (assuming either C# or Java), and have double-checked that what I am doing should match.

Is there any chance that someone could have a browse over this, and see what I'm doing wrong? I've stepped through it at smaller levels, and stopped it on specific iterations of the algorithm (by unrolling the top loop, and explicitly calling the algorithm a set number of times) and everything seems to work until we get to the very last set of points/pixels.

I use a class (called Matrix) to access the list, and wrap any out of bounds values.

The code for the algorithm is as follows:

```
class World :
def genWorld (self, numcells, cellsize, seed):
    random.seed(seed)
    self.dims = numcells*cellsize
    self.seed = seed
    self.cells = Matrix(self.dims, self.dims)

    # set the cells at cellsize intervals
    half = cellsize/2
    for y in range(0, self.dims, cellsize):
        for x in range(0, self.dims, cellsize):
            self.cells[x,y] = random.random()

    scale = 1.0
    samplesize = cellsize
    while samplesize > 1:
        self._diamondSquare(samplesize, scale)
        scale *= 0.8
        samplesize = int(samplesize/2)

    # I need to sort out the problem with the diamond-square algo that causes it to make the weird gridding pattern

def _sampleSquare(self, x, y, size, value):
    half = size/2
    a = self.cells[x-half, y-half]
    b = self.cells[x+half, y-half]
    c = self.cells[x-half, y+half]
    d = self.cells[x+half, y+half]

    res = min(((a+b+c+d+value)/5.0), 1.0)
    self.cells[x, y] = res

def _sampleDiamond(self, x, y, size, value):
    half = size/2
    a = self.cells[x+half, y]
    b = self.cells[x-half, y]
    c = self.cells[x, y+half]
    d = self.cells[x, y-half]

    res = min(((a+b+c+d+value)/5.0), 1.0)
    self.cells[x, y] = res

def _diamondSquare(self, stepsize, scale):
    half = int(stepsize/2)
    for y in range(half, self.dims+half, stepsize):
        for x in range(half, self.dims+half, stepsize):
            self._sampleSquare(x, y, stepsize, random.random()*scale)

    for y in range(0, self.dims, stepsize):
        for x in range(0, self.dims, stepsize):
            self._sampleDiamond(x+half, y, stepsize, random.random()*scale)
            self._sampleDiamond(x, y+half, stepsize, random.random()*scale)
```

and is called with:

```
w = World()
w.genWorld(16, 16, 1) # a 256x256 square world, since the numcells is multiplied by the cellsize to give us the length of ONE side of the resulting grid
```

then I save to file to check the result:

```
file = io.open("sample.raw",'wb')
arr = [int(i * 255) for i in w.cells.cells] # w.cells.cells should not have a value >= 1.0, so what's going on?
ind = 0
for a in arr:
    if a > 255:
        print ("arr["+str(ind)+"] ::= "+str(a))
    ind += 1
file.write(bytearray(arr))
file.close()
```

which gives the result:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQHCY.png]

**EDIT:** Okay, so it appears that I managed to get it working. I swapped from using functions for working out the diamond and square steps to doing it all in the _diamondSquare() function, but this wasn't the only thing. I also found out that random.random() provides values in the range [0.0 ->1.0), when I was expecting values in the range [-1.0 -> 1.0). After I corrected this, everything started working properly, which was a relief.

Thanks for the advice everyone, here's the working code in case anyone else is struggling with something similar:

**Random Function**

```
# since random.random() gives a value in the range [0.0 -> 1.0), I need to change it to [-1.0 -> 1.0)
def rand():
    mag = random.random()
    sign = random.random()
    if sign >=0.5:
        return mag
    return mag * -1.0
```

**Matrix class**

```
class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.cells = [0 for i in range(width*height)]
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.max_elems = width*height

    def _getsingleindex(self, ind):
        if ind < 0:
            ind *= -1
        while ind >= self.max_elems:
            ind -= self.max_elems
        return ind

    def _getmultiindex(self, xind, yind):
        if xind < 0:
            xind *= -1
        if yind < 0:
            yind *= -1

        while xind >= self.width:
            xind -= self.width
        while yind >= self.height:
            yind -= self.height
        return xind + (yind*self.height)

    def __getitem__(self, inds):
        # test that index is an integer, or two integers, and throw an indexException if not
        if hasattr(inds, "__len__"):
            if len(inds) > 1:
                return self.cells[self._getmultiindex(int(inds[0]), int(inds[1]))]
        return self.cells[self._getsingleindex(int(inds))]

    def __setitem__(self, inds, object):
        # test that index is an integer, or two integers, and throw an indexException if not
        if hasattr(inds, "__len__"):
            if len(inds) > 1:
                self.cells[self._getmultiindex(int(inds[0]),int(inds[1]))] = object
                return self.cells[self._getmultiindex(int(inds[0]),int(inds[1]))]
        self.cells[self._getsingleindex(int(inds))] = object
        return self.cells[self._getsingleindex(int(inds))]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.cells)
```

**The Actual Diamond-Square Generation**

```
# performs the actual 2D generation
class World:
    def genWorld (self, numcells, cellsize, seed, scale = 1.0):
        random.seed(seed)
        self.dims = numcells*cellsize
        self.seed = seed
        self.cells = Matrix(self.dims, self.dims)
        mountains = Matrix(self.dims, self.dims)

        # set the cells at cellsize intervals
        for y in range(0, self.dims, cellsize):
            for x in range(0, self.dims, cellsize):
                # this is the default, sets the heights randomly
                self.cells[x,y] = random.random()


        while cellsize > 1:
            self._diamondSquare(cellsize, scale)
            scale *= 0.5
            cellsize = int(cellsize/2)

        for i in range(len(mountains)):
            self.cells[i] = self.cells[i]*0.4 + (mountains[i]*mountains[i])*0.6

    def _diamondSquare(self, stepsize, scale):
        half = int(stepsize/2)
        # diamond part
        for y in range(half, self.dims+half, stepsize):
            for x in range(half, self.dims+half, stepsize):
                self.cells[x, y] = ((self.cells[x-half, y-half] + self.cells[x+half, y-half] + self.cells[x-half, y+half] + self.cells[x+half, y+half])/4.0) + (rand()*scale)

        # square part
        for y in range(0, self.dims, stepsize):
            for x in range(0, self.dims, stepsize):
                self.cells[x+half,y] = ((self.cells[x+half+half, y] + self.cells[x+half-half, y] + self.cells[x+half, y+half] + self.cells[x+half, y-half])/4.0)+(rand()*scale)
                self.cells[x,y+half] = ((self.cells[x+half, y+half] + self.cells[x-half, y+half] + self.cells[x, y+half+half] + self.cells[x, y+half-half])/4.0)+(rand()*scale)
```

**Main Function** (added for completeness)

```
# a simple main function that uses World to create a 2D array of diamond-square values, then writes it to a file
def main():
    w = World()
    w.genWorld(20, 16, 1)

    mi = min(w.cells.cells)
    ma = max(w.cells.cells) - mi

    # save the resulting matrix to an image file
    file = io.open("sample.raw",'wb')
    maxed = [(i-mi)/ma for i in w.cells.cells]
    arr = [int(i * 255) for i in maxed]

    file.write(bytearray(arr))
    file.close()
```

Comment: here few of mine related QAs for comparison [Diamond-square algorithm not working](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36258843/2521214) and [Island map generator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36647622/2521214) both are in C++. Now your result looks like you are not correctly limiting randomness between subdivisions , but can be also some weird recursion error. I dismissed the recursion from start as it leads to too many problems instead I come with iterative version which is faster and simpler (see the linked QAs).

Comment: Uh... why are the functions in the class not indented?

Comment: You are using `scale*=0.8` try `scale*=0.5` instead. And I would move it out of that condition

Comment: @DerpfacePython the indentation seems to have gotten a little screwy when I copied the code into the question, it's all indented correctly in the actual source file

Comment: @Spektre move it out of what condition? I had it at 0.5 before, and the artefacts seemed even worse like that. Also, I didn't think this was recursion?

Comment: oh I see now its `while` not `if` my bad. Yes you're iterating too, why do you have 2 diamond steps per single square or am I misreading again (no `{ }` inside `for` confuses me sorry I do not use python so I do not know if the last diamond sample is inside or after the `for` loop)? Another thing is you are averaging the value with neighbors which is suspicious `(a+b+c+d+value)/5` should not it be `(a+b+c+d)/4 + value` instead? Did you test range checking?  If your square is not coded properly it can access items outside array (doing a mess)

Comment: I originally had it as it was in the website I linked, as "(a+b+c+d)/4.0 + value", but that can produce values in the range [0.0-2.0), while I was after values in the range [0.0-1.0).  also, the two diamond steps are to take into account the different starting positions on each row for filling in the diamonds