# 2D Isometric(diamond shape) game engine - Reversed sprites

Tags: c++, 2d, sfml, coordinate-systems, isometric

All my sprites are reversed when I try to draw my isometric map.

Here is the tileset.png mentionned in the following code :
[image]

Object.h/Object.cpp

**I can use them to draw tiles, UI element, etc. ...**

```
#pragma once

class Object {
public:
    //FUNCTIONS
    Object();
    void addComponent(float value);
    int getComponent(float index);
    void editComponent(float index, float value);
    void deleteComponent(float index);

private:
    vector<int> components;
};

#include "Object.cpp"
```

-

```
#pragma once

//FUNCTIONS
Object::Object() {
    //...
}

void Object::addComponent(float value) {
    components.push_back(value);
}

int Object::getComponent(float index) {
    return components[index];
}

void Object::editComponent(float index, float value) {
    components[index] = value;
}

void Object::deleteComponent(float index) {
    components.erase(components.begin() + index);
}
```

**Note:** I may have weird includes, I'm struggling with visual studio ha ha.

Scene.h/Scene.cpp

**Handle data & graphics**

```
#pragma once

class Scene {
public:
    Scene(float w, float h, int mapx, int mapy, int tilesize, int mapwidth, int mapheight);
    void run();

    void addLayer();
    void loadTileset(sf::String url);
    void loadUiTileset(sf::String url);

    //functions
    //...

    //getters
    //...

    //setters
    //...

private:
    sf::RenderWindow window;

    float width;
    float height;

    int nb_layers;

    int map_x;
    int map_y;
    int map_width;
    int map_height;
    int tile_size;
    int selected_tile_index;

    sf::RenderTexture texture;
    sf::Sprite tile;
    sf::Sprite map;
    sf::Texture tileset;
    vector<Object> tiles;

    sf::Texture uiTileset;

    //private functions
    void updateMap();

    //...

    void processEvent();
    void update(sf::Time deltaTime);
    void render();

    //...
};

#include "Scene.cpp"
```

-

```
#pragma once

//functions
Scene::Scene(float w, float h, int mapx, int mapy, int tilesize, int mapwidth, int mapheight) : window(sf::VideoMode(w, h), "Editor") {
    width = w;
    height = h;

    map_x = mapx;
    map_y = mapy;
    map_width = mapwidth;
    map_height = mapheight;

    tile_size = tilesize;

    selected_tile_index = 0;//default

    nb_layers = 0;
}

void Scene::run() {
    sf::Clock clock;
    sf::Time timeSinceLastUpdate = sf::Time::Zero;
    sf::Time TimePerFrame = sf::seconds(1.f / 60.f);

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        processEvent();

        timeSinceLastUpdate += clock.restart();

        while (timeSinceLastUpdate > TimePerFrame) {
            timeSinceLastUpdate -= TimePerFrame;

            processEvent();
            update(TimePerFrame);
        }

        render();
    }
}

void Scene::addLayer() {
    nb_layers += 1;

    int tile_x = map_x,
        tile_y = map_y,
        num_layer = nb_layers - 1,
        layer_pos = (num_layer * tile_size) / 2,
        tile_zOrder = -1;

    tile_y -= layer_pos;

    int x = map_x,
        y = map_y;

    for (int h = 0; h < map_height; h++) {
        for (int w = 0; w < map_width; w++) {
            tile_zOrder = (w * (h + 1)) + (num_layer * 10);

            x = carthesianToIsometric(tile_x, tile_y)[0];
            y = carthesianToIsometric(tile_x, tile_y)[1] - layer_pos;

            cout << x << ", " << y << endl;

            Object tile;
            tile.addComponent(selected_tile_index);
            tile.addComponent(x);
            tile.addComponent(y);
            tile.addComponent(tile_zOrder);
            tile.addComponent(num_layer);

            tiles.push_back(tile);
            tile_x += tile_size;
        }
        tile_x = 0;
        tile_y += tile_size;
    }

    updateMap();
}

void Scene::loadTileset(sf::String url) {
    if (!tileset.loadFromFile(url))
    {
        cout << std::string(url) << "couldn't be loaded..." << endl;
    }
}

void Scene::loadUiTileset(sf::String url) {
    if (!uiTileset.loadFromFile(url))
    {
        cout << std::string(url) << "couldn't be loaded..." << endl;
    }
}

//getters
//...

//setters
//...

//private functions
void Scene::updateMap() {
    int tile_position_x = 0,
        tile_position_y = 0;

    int tile_x = 0,
        tile_y = 0;

    if (!texture.create(map_width * tile_size, (map_height * tile_size) / 2))
        cout << "Texture couldn't be loaded... " << endl;

    texture.clear(sf::Color(133, 118, 104, 255));

    sf::Sprite image;
    image.setTexture(tileset);
    int tileset_width = image.getGlobalBounds().width,
        tileset_height = image.getGlobalBounds().height;

    tile.setTexture(tileset);

    for (int tile_index = 0; tile_index < tiles.size(); tile_index++) {
        tile_position_x = getTilePosition(tileset_width, tileset_height, tiles[tile_index].getComponent(0), tile_size)[0];
        tile_position_y = getTilePosition(tileset_width, tileset_height, tiles[tile_index].getComponent(0), tile_size)[1];

        tile.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(tile_position_x, tile_position_y, tile_size, tile_size));

        tile_x = tiles[tile_index].getComponent(1);
        tile_y = tiles[tile_index].getComponent(2);

        tile.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(tile_x, tile_y));

        texture.draw(tile);
    }

    map.setTexture(texture.getTexture());
}

void Scene::processEvent() {
    sf::Event event;

    while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
        switch (event.type) {
        case sf::Event::Closed:
            window.close();
            break;

        case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
            if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape)
                window.close();
            break;
        }
    }
}

void Scene::update(sf::Time deltaTime) {
    //REMEMBER: distance = speed * time
    //MOVEMENT, ANIMATIONS ETC. ..
}

void Scene::render() {
    window.clear();

    window.draw(map);

    window.display();
}
```

main.cpp

```
#pragma once
//global functions + main headers + class headers =>
#include "globalfunctions.h"

int main() {
    int map_width = 15,
        map_height = 15,
        tile_size = 64;

    float scene_width = map_width * tile_size,
        scene_height = (map_height * tile_size) / 2;

    Scene engine(scene_width, scene_height, 0, 0, tile_size, map_width, map_height);
    engine.loadTileset("tileset.png");
    //engine.loadUiTileset("menu.png");

    engine.addLayer();
    //...

    engine.run();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

globalfunctions.h

**Some utility functions.**
getTilePosition(...) allow me to get x, y on a texture with a given tile index. Example : if I want to draw the tile n°0 of the tileset texture.

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<float> getTilePosition(float tileset_width, float tileset_height, float tile_index, float tile_size) {//In a tileset
    float tileX = 0,
        tileY = 0,
        tilePerLine = 0;

    tilePerLine = tileset_width / tile_size;

    tileY = floor(tile_index / tilePerLine);
    tileX = ((tile_index + 1) - (tileY * tilePerLine)) - 1;

    tileX *= tile_size;
    tileY *= tile_size;

    vector<float> coords;
        coords.push_back(tileX);
        coords.push_back(tileY);

    return coords;
}

vector<int> carthesianToIsometric(int x, int y) {
    vector<int> coords;

    float isoX = (x - y) / 2,
        isoY = (x + y) / 4;

    coords.push_back(isoX);
    coords.push_back(isoY);

    return coords;
}

#include "Object.h"
#include "Scene.h"

//...
```

And here, the WTF result I get :

[image]

Thanks for reading all that weird code !

**Edit :**

When I change

```
tile.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(tile_x, tile_y));
```

to

```
tile.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(0, 0));
```

in `updateMap()` from scene.cpp :

[image]

Unfortunatly, I cannot explain why. Maybe it will help you to understand the problem.

Comment: Could it be that the y axis goes in the opposite direction of what you're assuming?

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks for your answer ! Why the x axis would reverse a tile ?

Comment: @Madz Then I can't solve your problem, but I think I can give you a couple tips to work on your own. 1) Check your image loader, if possible move *that* into an external project and just load up an image to test 2) Check your image formatting, it's possible that it expects the image to be flipped 3) If all else fails you can just save your images upside down.

Comment: It is just Y-axis mirror (I see no X-axis mirroring) on most  gfx engines screen is going down with increasing `y` coordinate. Problem is most likely in `texture.draw(tile)` which I do not see in the posted code.

Comment: Even adding layer, they goes in reverse. What do you mean by you do not see it in the posted code ? draw is an sfml function, i did not wrote it. Do you suggest I try to reverse coordinates ? I have 0 idea about how ( T _ T )

Comment: Big thanks ! It was the draw(), after you suggested it, I did some research and now my problem is gone @Spektre . Really thanks

Comment: @Madz glad to be of help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone encounter the same problem :
As @Spectre suggested it was a problem of the sfml function draw().

http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=6903.0
You need to use display on the `sf::renderTexture` after your cleared it.